# Entity Framework Multiple selects with one DB call

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Here is my class (I am using Entity Framework 5; .Net Framework 4.0):

```
public class Role
{
public int RoleId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }


[NotMapped]
public List<RolePrompt> RolePrompts { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public List<RoleFeature> RoleFeatures { get; set; }
}

public class RolePrompt
{
  public int RolePromptId{get;set;}
  public int RoleId{get;set;}
  public int PromptId{get;set;}

  public Role Role{get;set;}
}

public class RoleFeature
{
  public int RoleFeatureId{get;set;}
  public int RoleId{get;set;}
  public int FeatureId{get;set;}

  public Role Role{get;set;}
}
```

How would I go about loading a Role object with all the sub objects populated with ONE db call?  I know how to do it with multiple repository calls.

```
Role role = roleRepository.Find(roleId);
role.RolePrompts = rolePromptsRepository.FindByRoleId(roleId); 
role.RoleFeatures = roleFeaturesRepository.FindByRoleId(roleId);
```

... and so on

The above code calls the DB multiple times.  I want the Role object to be loaded with RolePrompts and RoleFeatures in one db call.

Comment: Have you looked into the .Include() function?

Comment: .Include() will not work because its not mapped

Comment: Any particular reason you want to keep it that way? They seem like related records, and you already have a relationship in the other direction.

Comment: Not sure what you  mean.  I cannot add a 2 way reference because it will end up in a cyclical reference issue.  I hope I understood your query.

Comment: Cyclical reference is only a problem for cascade delete, if you don't need cascade delete disable it.

Comment: Can you explain why it would create a cyclical reference? It seems like two simple one-to-many relationships, as far as I can tell. When I hear "cyclical" I usually think of a parent/child relationship, or a one-to-one with a principal and dependent record.

Comment: @Jeremy : Do you want me to remove the [NotMapped] attribute from the Role class?  If I do that EF creates a weird column in the Role table called RolePrompts_Id.  As far as the prompts go - its one to many.  However for the feature, its many to many mapping.

Comment: @VijayV after reading some of the comments, I think  you might be misunderstanding what EF code first does. Maybe you could just tell us what relationships you are trying to accomplish and we could respond with an answer, because it sounds like you are just trying to create a many-to-many relationship but using the `NotMapped` as a workaround.

Comment: @SOfanatic - There is a many to many relationship with the Role and Feature tables and a one to many relationship with the Role and Prompts table.  Hence the sub classes that relate Roles and Prompts and Roles and Features.  However what I am trying to achieve here is when I try to load a Role, I want these RoleFeatures and RolePrompts to be loaded with those.  Does this make sense? I hope I am explaining myself correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> There is a many to many relationship with the Role and Feature tables and a one to many relationship with the Role and Prompts table.

You need this class structure:

```
public class Role
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RoleFeature> RoleFeatures { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RolePrompt> RolePrompts { get; set; }
}

public class RolePrompt
{
    public int RolePromptId { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}

public class RoleFeature
{
    public int RoleFeatureId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Role>()
.HasMany(r => r.RoleFeatures).WithMany(f => f.Roles)
.Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("RoleId")
    .MapRightKey("RoleFeatureId")
    .ToTable("RoleRoleFeatures"));
```

And this will give you this table structure:

[image: Table Structure]

Then you can go ahead and use `Include` to load `Prompts` and `Features`.

Answer (score 0):

I created a little helper method to do this.

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> Include(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
{
    IQueryable<T> dbQuery = context.Set<T>();

    // Apply eager loading
    foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> inc in includes)
    {
        dbQuery = dbQuery.Include<T, object>(inc);
    }

    return dbQuery.AsNoTracking();
}
```

'context' is a property that I set up of my class that hold the current DbContext

You can then call it by doing this

```
var myData = context.Roles.Where(x => x.RoleId == roleid).Include("RolePrompts", "RoleFeatures")
```

Comment: This will not work - as  have a [NotMapped] property in my Role class to the RolePrompt and RoleFeature classes.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Use a fluent mapping to add .WillCascadeOnDelete(false); to the navigation properties RolePrompts and RoleFeatures so you can build